# how to register unique values? in the spreadsheet google app script web

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, unique

i need a help to register only unique values ​​inside the google spreadsheet behind the web script app

currently to save I use this script, practical find a way to block the launch if you already have values ​​the same values ​​in the spreadsheet.

basically there are two fields "cod" and "val"

if "cod" and "val" have already been registered before, it would need to show a message that these data are repeated.

I tried to do a check, but you can only do it in one "cod" field,

I would like to do it in both "cod" and "val" fields

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZfIqw6_pkt1AdWsayyk1LdW_I6lU2yjsY1VfxfJneCA/edit#gid=0

```js
function save_on_sheet(Data){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZfIqw6_pkt1AdWsayyk1LdW_I6lU2yjsY1VfxfJneCA/edit#gid=0");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("page");

  const cod = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues().map(r => r[0].toString().toLowerCase());

  const posicaoIndex = cod.indexOf(Data.cod.toString().toLowerCase());

  if (posicaoIndex === -1) {

   ws.appendRow([
           Data.cod,
           Data.val
   ])

   return 'NEW';

  } else {

   return 'DUPLICATE';

  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
      <label for="cod">COD:</label>
      <input type="text" id="cod"><br><br>
      <label for="val">VALUE:</label>
      <input type="text" id="val"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="SAVE UNIQUE SHEET" onclick="save()">
  </body>

  <script>

   function save(){
     Data = {}
     Data.cod = document.getElementById("cod").value;
     Data.val = document.getElementById("val").value;

     google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(retorno).save_on_sheet(Data);

   }

     function retorno(mensagem_retorno){

      alert(mensagem_retorno);

  }

  </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample code:

```
function save_on_sheet(Data){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZfIqw6_pkt1AdWsayyk1LdW_I6lU2yjsY1VfxfJneCA/edit#gid=0");
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("page");

  const dataVal = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow()-1, 2).getDisplayValues();
  Logger.log(dataVal);

  for(var i=0; i<dataVal.length;i++){
    var rowData = dataVal[i];

    if(rowData[0]==Data.cod.toString().toLowerCase() && rowData[1]==Data.val.toString().toLowerCase()){
      //Exit function, duplicate found
      return 'DUPLICATE';
    }
  }

  //No duplicate found. Append new data
  ws.appendRow([
      Data.cod,
      Data.val
  ]);

  return 'NEW';

}
```

### What it does?

1. Get `cod` and `values` data in the spreadsheet using [Range.getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues) which will return a 2-d array of string values.
2. Loop each row value and compare `cod` and `values` to `Data.cod` and `Data.values`. If match found, return `"DUPLICATE"`, if no match found, append the `Data` and return `"NEW"`

Comment: Hi @Fragosojp thanks for accepting the answer, I have thought of a simpler approach, please refer to the updated answer. Let me know if you encountered some issues.